# How to prove that the sequence $a_n=\tan{\frac{1}{n}}$ is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

In my notebook there is this problem which has instructions how to solve it, and one of the instructions says that I am supposed to show that $a_n=\tan{\frac{1}{n}}$ is decreasing for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I have been trying to prove it with manipulating it to $\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n}}{\cos\frac{1}{n}}$ and then showing that it is decreasing, or using induction, but those attempts failed eventually.

Any hints how to prove this ?

Comment: What do you "know" about $\tan x$ or more specifically, what are you allowed to use? Do you know that $\tan(x)$, as a real-valued function, is strictly increasing for $x \in (-\tfrac{\pi}{2},\tfrac{\pi}{2})$...?

Comment: @StackTD While trying to solve this I realized $\tan(x)$ is strictly increasing on that interval, but still wasn't able to make any use of that fact.

Comment: @GrigoriPerelman As $n$ increases, you're essentially going from right to left on the graph. If it is increasing from left to right, then it's decreasing from right to left.

Comment: @tau20 Note $n\mapsto\frac1n$ is decreasing!

Comment: (you deleted your previous comment?) -- Note that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, you have $0 < \tfrac{1}{n} \le 1$ and $(0,1] \subset (-\tfrac{\pi}{2},\tfrac{\pi}{2})$.

Comment: @StackTD I resolved the issues concerning the deleted comment before you made the comment above. I understand now on the intuitive level pretty clearly that the sequence is decreasing, but I still can't think how to prove it properly, besides the proof that Naren posted below, which is quite nice btw. except that I am not familiar with those trig. identities, and I would like to know if there is another way which doesn't rely on those as much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $$a_{n+1}-a_{n} =\tan\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)-\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\tan\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)(1+a_na_{n+1})=-\tan\left(\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right)(1+a_n a_{n+1}) <0$$  As seen $a_{n+1}-a_{n} <0$ and hence $a_n$ is  decreasing sequence. We use the compound angle for of $$\tan(A-B)(1+\tan A\tan B)= \tan A - \tan B$$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that the function $$f(x)=\tan \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ is decreasing for all $x\geq 1$ by using differentiation.

Comment: I am supposed to prove it by using tools you learn in the real-analysis 1 course prior to derivatives etc. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @GrigoriPerelman I'm sorry! My calculus knowledge is generally limited to Calc 1 and 2.